# C++ Reading memory from a string

Tags: c++, winapi, memory

I was trying to read a memory from explorer.exe. With a program process hacker I found that on the address `0xfa07f8` this string is stored: `\??\C:\Program Files\Process Hacker 2\ProcessHacker.exe`

When I try to read the string of this address, I get only the first character of the string back.
The '\' char.
How can I read the whole string?

```
char buffer[255] = { 0 };
unsigned addr = 0xfa07f8;
if (ReadProcessMemory(proc, (LPVOID)addr, &buffer, sizeof(buffer), NULL))
{
    MessageBoxA(NULL, buffer, NULL, NULL);
}
```

Comment: The string will be in Unicode UTF-16 and every other byte will be 0 for the ASCII characters.

Comment: What do you see when you inspect the contents of `buffer` with your debugger?

Comment: @RichardCritten Does windows use UTF-16 internally?

Comment: You probably read a `bstr_t` value from that address, the `\??\\` represent the prefixed string length, that you see printable characters there is just by chance.

Comment: I just tried to read a different string, `en-US`, and it's giving me the same result. `MessageBoxA` is displaying only 'e'.

Comment: btw even when its obvious what you intend to ask it is better to actually formulate a question, even it is just "Whats wrong here?" or "How can I read the whole string?", sometimes there is a difference between those two

Comment: If you're reading UTF-16 characters then `MessageBoxA` is probably not the right choice. What happens if you try using `MessageBoxW`?

Comment: @CaptainGiraffe  Internally MS-Windows is UTF-16le.

Comment: @JeduMiSePalacinke `MessageBoxA is displaying` -- Use the debugger memory window, not `MessageBoxA`.  If you're going to go this low-level, at the very least you should be watching the memory in a debugger.

Comment: @jkb MessageBoxW worked. Add that as an actual reply.

Comment: @JeduMiSePalacinke If you were to change the title of your question with your new found knowledge to make it accessible, that would be great.

Comment: @TedLyngmo yes it worked. just replaced the MessageBoxA function with MessageBoxA

Comment: @JeduMiSePalacinke Of course ... tired brain here :) It's cleaner without `&` though. `buffer` would be passed as a `char*` while `&buffer` is passed as a `char(*)[255]` - The `LPVOID` doesn't care but in a different context it could get ugly. [example](https://godbolt.org/z/aEe4oPs5h)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are reading wide characters from the process memory. `MessageBoxA` is for displaying "narrow" characters.

To display wide characters, use `MessageBoxW`.